# Cypress add delay to API call

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to test for a bug caused by a race condition based on which of two API calls returns first. To do this, I'd like to create a Cypress test that adds some delay to one of the routes by a second or two. I don't see anything documented on how to do that. Is there any easy way to do that? I tried stubbing `window.fetch` but it didn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

As of Cypress 6.0 you should use `cy.intercept()` instead of `cy.route()`. You can work with the request or response before its sent to the browser:

```
cy.intercept({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '*/pathtointercept/**',
}, (req) => {
  //send the request with a delay value
  req.reply({ delay: 30000 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `cy.route()` options as described in the [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Options):

```
cy.server()
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '**/user/adam',
  status: 200,
  response: {
    user: {name: 'adam'}
  },
  delay: 2000
})
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '**/user/jane',
  status: 200,
  response: {
    user: {name: 'jane'}
  },
  delay: 0
})
```

In order to make this case use "real" data, you may want to simply record the response of the route you want to delay by saving it to a fixture file, and then using that data to stub the route. There is an example of writing a [response to JSON here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#JSON)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer; I want the request to go through as normal, just with a delay. I don't want to have to provide a response object.

Comment: This isn't currently built in... Is there a reason you do not want to stub the response?

Comment: Because I have all my other responses going to a real (test) server, and if I stub one route, I'll likely have to stub all (or a lot of them) since the data depend on each other

Comment: There is a solution where you basically "record" the response, and use that to stub the cy.route

Comment: In realtime? Or you mean just take a snapshot of the result of one of the calls and paste it into cy.route?

Comment: Snapshot, You can save a result to the fixtures directory so you don't have to paste in your code

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't necessarily scale well; the snapshot may be valid at the time created, but weeks or months down the line the data may change enough that it no longer lines up, especially since it's pointing at a staging database that gets reimaged from production.

Comment: It is quite unbelievably frustrating to be able to forward a real response, delay a mock response, but not delay a real response. This being said, after a quick search, it appears that Cypress is still [trying to find itself in the area of network stubbing](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/687).